# what is the best method to upload images very quickly online uses laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

i tried to upload image and multiple images, locally it works well and it uploads and inserts very quickly even the big size of images, but online it takes a long time after upload and insert, i'm looking for many methods for uploading but too bad nothing was found...
can someone help me to find a package or a way.

**RegisterController.php**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            
            'image'    => ['bail','required','mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg','max:2048'],
            'images.*' => ['bail','required','mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg','max:2048']
        ]);
    }
protected function create(array $data)
    { 
        //image
        $user = new User();
        $request = app('request');
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
       {
        $image = $request->file('image'); 
        $path = $request->image->store('profiles');
        $user->image = $path;
        }
        $im = $user->image; 

        //images
        $dataim = array();
         if($request->hasFile('images')) 
         {
            foreach($request->images as $file) 
            {   
                $path = $file->store('profiles');
                array_push($dataim,$path);
            } 
         }
        $user->images=json_encode($dataim);
        $imm =$user->images;
        return User::create([
            'image'        => $im ,
            'images'       => $imm
        ]);
    }
```

**register.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>photo<span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" value="{{ old('image') }}">
            @error('image')
                <span class="invalid-feedback text-danger" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="divim">
            <label>photos<span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="images[]" value="{{ old('images') }}" multiple>
            @error('images')
                <span class="invalid-feedback text-danger" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
```

Comment: try some cdn service or `laravel queue` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues

Comment: @KamleshPaul thx for u answer i try it

Comment: use package like dropzone.. its have parallel attachments upload..